# Why did the space shuttle's altitude go down after reaching 108,000m?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, mission-design, velocity, acceleration

I recently took a look at this little data sheet by NASA: [Math and Science @ Work; Space Shuttle Ascent](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/466711main_AP_ST_ShuttleAscent.pdf)

| Time | Altitude | Velocity | Acceleration | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (s) | (m) | (m/s) | (m/s^2) |  |
| 20 | 1244 | 139 | 18.62 |  |
| 40 | 5377 | 298 | 16.37 |  |
| … | … | … | … |  |
| 280 | 105321 | 2651 | 13.92 |  |
| 300 | 107449 | 2915 | 14.90 |  |
| 320 | 108619 | 3203 | 15.97 |  |
| 340 | 108942 | 3516 | 17.15 | maximum altitude |
| 360 | 108543 | 3860 | 18.62 |  |
| 380 | 107690 | 4216 | 20.29 |  |
| 400 | 106539 | 4630 | 22.34 |  |
| 420 | 105142 | 5092 | 24.89 |  |
| 440 | 103775 | 5612 | 28.03 |  |
| 460 | 102807 | 6184 | 29.01 |  |
| 480 | 102552 | 6760 | 29.30 | maximum acceleration |
| 500 | 103297 | 7327 | 29.01 |  |
| 520 | 105069 | 7581 | 0.10 |  |

[original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqPgM.png)

> Note: Notice from the table that the altitude was negative at liftoff. Zero altitude can be described as a specific distance from the center of the Earth. Since the Earth is not perfectly spherical the location of the launch just happens to be below this specified point. Also, because this is a calculated number, some degree of error may be present.

As you can see, as time passes, the velocity and altitude of the rocket went up exponentially. ***[CORRECTION: I was mistaking this data for something else. The vel/alt does NOT go up exponentially, sorry about that!]***
However, why did the altitude stop increasing after reaching 108,000m, and then decrease after that?

Also, why was the acceleration rate inconsistent throughout the takeoff? Why was it the highest when the altitude was decreasing?

Thank you, I'm working on a project related to the Rocket Equation and am wondering if this is worth mentioning in said project. :)

Comment: The acceleration is inconsistent, because the thrust is inconsistent. SRB thrust is shaped, and the main engines are throttled. Along with the SRBs running out part way.

Comment: "*why does the velocity basically "stop" after reaching 108,000m*". Only the vertical component of the velocity. The total velocity shown in the third column is still increasing.  The target altitude seems to be 105km. But, the first time the vehicle hits that target, the total velocity is only 2600 m/s. It is far far below the required velocity of 7200 m/s required to stay in orbit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I've adjusted the format of  your question and fixed a few words, have a look and feel free to edit further.

Comment: "go up exponentially" is wildly misleading and inaccurate. The curve is, indeed, exactly unlike "exponentially".

Comment: Partial answer: to "*why is the acceleration rate inconsistent throughout the takeoff? Why is it the highest when the altitude is decreasing?*" the acceleration increases as thrust remains constant while vehicle mass is decreasing due to used fuel. (thrust actually increases a little bit as atmosphere thins, this would not be obvious in your dataset). The abrupt drop in acceleration at 2 minutes is when the thrust drops enormously, due to the Solid Motors completing their burn.

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/ "getting to space is easy. The problem is staying there.... To avoid falling back into the atmosphere, you have to go sideways really, really fast."

Comment: "However, why did the altitude stop increasing after reaching 108,000m, and then decrease after that?" - I believe this is not uncommon with long-burning low-TWR upper stages (e.g., Centaur), where the first stage would "lob" the upper stage above the target orbital altitude to help give the upper stage enough time to circularize. The Space Shuttle doesn't appear to have a particularly low TWR, though, so I'm not sure why the flight profile is what it is in this case.

Comment: The listed acceleration numbers felt a bit off initially. If you accelerate at $18 m/s^2$ then after $20$ seconds your speed would be $360 m/s$, right? I guess the rate of change of (vertical component of) speed is the listed figure minus Earth gravity ($9.81 m/s^2$)? Assuming that early on the acceleration is more or less straight up. Makes sense in a way for the listed acceleration is what the astronauts (and the structure) needs to endure.

Comment: The high-altitude altitude drop-off was informally referred to as "droop," IIRC. The trajectory was shaped this way for performance optimization reasons (reflecting tons of analysis and "big physics"). An interesting independent question would inquire about the specific reasons behind said "droop."

Comment: @A.L that's a much more attractive looking table. But at [31% longer than the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfmzE.png) I'm wondering if that formatting technique has a way to reduce the amount of vertical whitespace above and below the numbers (which is currently 2.6 times the font height)?

Comment: @PcMan I stand corrected. I believe I got that confused for something else I saw.. ^^;

Answer (score 36):

The drop in acceleration around 40s into the flight is the shuttle throttling down to reduce the aerodynamic load on the vehicle. It then accelerates when past this point.

The drop in acceleration at 2 mins into the flight is due to the solid rocket boosters running out and being discarded.

Acceleration then continues to build, as the thrust from the engines is constant, but the vehicle mass gets less and less as the fuel is consumed. The peak acceleration is due to the low mass when the tank is almost empty, and not related to the altitude.

In fact, towards the end of the ascent the shuttle is throttling down as the mass goes down, to keep the acceleration below 30m/s/s, for structural reasons.

The change in altitude is due to the shuttle overshooting its initial altitude, so it can put all its thrust into horizontal velocity after that. So it actually falls a little as it continues to burn and accelerate horizontally, but eventually this horizontal velocity results in it not falling anymore (as the earth falls away below it at the same rate).

Comment: OP is asking two separate questions, and although I think the acceleration aspect is covered here, the _why_ of the altitude loss is poorly explained. It's fully possible to fly an ascent profile which never has any downward velocity. I suspect there is a complicated reason lurking behind the choice of profile, and would welcome further info.

Comment: It has to do with PEG guidance achieving the velocity target; it's explained on pages 4-5 through 4-12 of the Ascent Guidance Workbook, but I'd be lying if I said I understood it. https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC%20GNC%20ASC%202102%20Ascent%20Guidance%20and%20Navigation%20and%20Flight%20Control%20Workbook.pdf

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, the Saturn V did the same thing getting to parking orbit.  Different vehicles with different propulsion and staging, but the outcome is essentially the same:

[image: Saturn V altitude]

Source: [*Saturn V Flight Manual*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19750063889).  Note that the graph labels for the second (S-II) and third (S-IVB) stage cutoffs are incorrectly swapped.  The source explains the third stage's burn as an insertion into the Earth parking orbit:

> The S-IVB first burn inserts the vehicle into a 100 nautical mile (NMI) altitude, nearly circular, EPO.

Innovine's answer provides one explanation: the vehicle has surpassed the desired altitude, but needs to gain speed to stay in orbit.  Another way to look at it is in terms of apogee and perigee.  The vehicle has reached maximum altitude (apogee), but the perigee intersects the ground.  Another burn is necessary to raise the perigee to orbital altitude.

Comment: PEG guidance again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the numbers. The acceleration is high at the start (full force!). It drops a bit at 40 seconds but then increases steadily due to mass loss. Between 100 and 120 seconds, there is a sudden drop in the acceleration. The two main thrusters are thrown off. From the lower value the acceleration increase continuously. In a somewhat linear fashion. When the highest altitude is reached the shuttle moves horizontally after which it moves toward a lower orbit. The acceleration is increasing towards a max around 480 seconds. Around 500 seconds the force is turned off and the shuttle has reached a height of about 105 kilometers. This height will increase until a stable orbit is reached.

Comment: This answer does not add anything new beyond the [other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53738/40257). Once the main engines are shut down the orbit does not change unless another propulsive maneuver is performed (or hit the atmosphere).

Answer (score 0):

For more information take another look at the graph, you see the ascent graph versus the thrust and acceleration:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/Shuttle_And_Misc_Pictures/ascent.gif
Additional information about the shuttle:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/

Comment: Ken, welcome to space stack exchange. You might notice that I linked to a document from your extremely valuable site in a comment on the first answer. Stack exchange sites are quite different from most "forum" sites - there's a big difference between answers and comments, for one thing. I suggest you spend some time reading q&a's here before diving in. Your vast store of shuttle info is going to be a real asset here!